# Passing target name in dependencies which can be formatted in a makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What I would like to do is to get the target name in the dependency and be able to format it.
For example if the target is `Objs/foo.o` I would like to make the dependency to `Sources1/foo.c`, I tried doing this

```
$(filter %.o,$(OBJS)): $(filter %/$(patsubst %.o,%,$(notdir $@)).cpp, $(SRCS))
```

but none of them works. Where `OBJS` is a list of object files ex. `Objs/foo.o Objs/moo.o etc..`
Any help would be greatly appreciated. And SRCS is a list of different directories were sources can be located. Example Sources1/ and Sources2/ where I need to search in both those directories to find where the source is.

Comment: What's wrong with `Objs/%.o: %.c`?

Comment: I simplified this for illustration purposes. In the actual implementation I want to use filters to get the actual path of the source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`vpath` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Selective-Search.html) could take care of your issue. Here's an example:

```
OBJS:=Objs/foo.o Objs/bar.o

all: $(OBJS)

# This tells make to search for %.c files in Sources1 and Sources2.
vpath %.c Sources1 Sources2

$(filter %.o,$(OBJS)): Objs/%.o : %.c
    @echo $@ $^
```

When I run it here with `foo.c` in `Sources1` and `bar.c` in `Sources2`, I get the following output:

```
Objs/foo.o Sources1/foo.c
Objs/bar.o Sources2/bar.c
```

Comment: Thank a lot!! It worked :)

I would upvote it but I cannot :(

Thanks again!! :D